# ReferenceError: window is not defined, Firebase analytics

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, google-analytics

I get the error `ReferenceError: window is not defined` when trying to initialize Firebase analytics in my Next.js project.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
let analytics;
if (window !== undefined) {
   analytics = getAnalytics(app);
}

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User signed in
    const uid = user.uid;
    console.log(uid);
  } else {
    // User signed out.
  }
});

export { app, auth, analytics };
```

The issue was resolved in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69799682/firebase-analytics-with-next-js-window-not-definded); but the proposed solution doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: You have ```window !== undefined```.  The referenced post has ```window !== 'undefined'```.  Not sure if this is going to help though

Comment: @ewong your response combined with the latest answer resolved it for me! Thank you very much. The final solution was to check ```typeof window !== 'undefined'```. Was a bit careless and forgot about enclosing it in apostrophes. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `window` doesn't exist, you can't check its type.

Consider:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
```

Comment: Resolved it for me! Thanks very much.

Comment: Also, thanks so much for the work you do. Firebase is an absolute dream to work with. Really can't express enough gratitude for the work you folks do.