# Firebase Analytics ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-analytics

I just try to use Firebase Cloud Firestore with analytic service here is my index.js:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  //someConfigAreAlreadyHere
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

async function getAccount(db) {
    const Account = collection(db, 'Account');
    const accountSnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol);
    const accountList = accountSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return accountList;
  }

console.log(getAccount(db))
```

index.esm2017.js are all is default (It too long I can't show it in this post)

and I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at getOrCreateDataLayer (file:///D:/website/node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:176:23)
    at factory (file:///D:/website/node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1010:9)
    at Component.instanceFactory (file:///D:/website/node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1205:16)
    at Provider.getOrInitializeService (file:///D:/website/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:290:39)
    at Provider.initialize (file:///D:/website/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:234:31)
    at initializeAnalytics (file:///D:/website/node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1059:49)
    at getAnalytics (file:///D:/website/node_modules/@firebase/analytics/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1038:12)
    at file:///D:/website/index.js:22:19
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

Comment: Are you using this code in server environment because if you do then use firebase-admin to use firebase services because window object is not present in server environment hence the error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69799682/firebase-analytics-with-next-js-window-not-definded)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Analytics with Next.js - window not definded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69799682/firebase-analytics-with-next-js-window-not-definded)